# Shared code between projects as library without a repo?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I've two Swift PM projects, both use some common code which I would like to store perhaps in a separate project, say a library, which then these two would be able to import.

I've used swift init --type library and so on to build a library but is there any other documented way of including it in the other projects without having to submit it to github and providing the link to the repo to the swift package manager?

I'm thinking something around the lines of building the library project and having a script which copy pastes it wherever it needs to be to be accessible to the other projects (in their own directories if need be)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Swift Package Manager Usage documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#create-a-package) a swift package *is* designed to be used as a git repository.

> Simply put: a **[Swift] package is a git repository** with semantically versioned tags, that contains Swift sources and a Package.swift manifest file at its root.

That said, the [**dependencies** documentation section](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md#dependencies) states that the depedency path *can be a local path*.

> [Dependencies] is the list of packages that the package depends on. You can specify a URL (**or local path**) to any valid Swift package.

Note that the git tags are useful (needed) to manage which version of a dependent package is included.

```swift
// 1.5.8 ..< 2.0.0
.package(url: "path/SharedPackage", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.5.8")),
// Constraint to an arbitrary closed range.
.package(url: "path/SharedPackage", "1.2.3"..."1.2.8"),
// Branch and revision.
.package(url: "path/SharedPackage", .branch("develop")),
```

Key Points:

1. Treating the local package as the same local git repository could still align one's workflow with the Swift Package Manager design.
2. Some remote or additional git repository is not required because local dependency paths of the Swift package(s) can be used.

*Basically, using git in a more simplified and streamlined way may be worth considering for the local-only, some-shared-code use case.*